# Alterar la estructura un objeto con infinitos sub arrays en typescript

Tags: array, json, typescript, objeto

disculpen, tengo un problema con el siguiente objeto
[(Objeto actual)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T52EI.png)
Lo que necesito es convertir su estructura a la siguiente
[(Objeto que necesito)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iucgo.png), el cambio es que necesito eliminar el subnivel de "data" y todas las propiedades dentro de data tienen que subir un nivel en el objeto, logre crear la siguiente funcion para crear un objeto nuevo pero solo funciona con el primer nivel del objeto original, pero no se como aplicarlo a todos los hijos que pueden existir(los hijos pueden ser infinitos).

```
flatJson(json):void{
      for (var prop in json) {
         if(typeof json[prop] == 'object'){
               for (var nestedprop in json[prop]) {
                if(prop == "children"){
                  this.obj["children"] = json[prop];
                }else{
                  this.obj[nestedprop] = json[prop][nestedprop];
                }
                }
         } else{
            this.obj[prop] = json[prop];
         }
       }
   }
```

La funcion me devuelve un objeto y al momento de pasarlo a un json, este es el resultado
[(situacion actual del objeto)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3eg4.png), la funcion solo afecta el primer "nodo" por el momento y no todos los hijos que pueden existir, no tengo idea de como recorrer todo el objeto y aplicar el cambio que necesito, gracias por su apoyo

Intente cambiar la estructura de mi objeto pero solo me funciona con un solo nivel y yo necesito aplicar el cambio a n cantidad de subnivels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este tipo de situaciones se resuelven de forma sencilla usando recursión:

```
// recibe el arreglo
function flat(children) {
    // itera cada elemento del arreglo
    for (const child of children) {
        // asigna las propiedades del objeto `data` al objecto `child`
        Object.assign(child, child.data || {})
        // se elimina el objeto `data`
        delete child.data
        // se hace un paso recursivo
        flat(child.children || [])
    }
}

// esto es el arreglo children del `root`
flat(root.children)

console.log(root)
```